# The query has timed out.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The query has timed out

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, azure-sql-database

Getting this error when trying to execute the procedure from spring's transaction.

> SQL state [HY008]; error code [0]; The query has timed out.; nested
>   exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The
>   query has timed out.

This occurs at 10 min when the dataset is large.
Using the Azure SQL server for this.

Tried:

1. @transaction(timeout=18000)
2. Azure DB is not showing the connection properties to edit the remote query time out time option.

Comment: So, why do you think taht a query taking 10 MINUTES is not a problem in itself? Why treat the symptoms instead of fixing the problem?

Comment: @TomTom you are right, but in my case, the data set is too large to finish in 10 min.
it will take a little more than 10 min.
anyway, I fixed my problem by JDBC template timeout option for now.
will try to reduce the time query is taking

Comment: Hi @vivekpandey, congratulation that you solved the issue now. I help you post it as answer then others can know it.  You can think about  mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulation you solved the timeout error now:

"I fixed my problem by JDBC template timeout option for now. Will try to reduce the time query is taking"

I help you post it is as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members.